# strptime format not matching even though it looks correct?

Tags: python, locale, strptime

I'm getting an error when trying to parse datetime:

```
ValueError: ("time data '2019-07-05T10:19:42+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

the line that is generating this error is:

```
df['yearmonth'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.strptime(row['createdAt'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').strftime("%Y%m"), axis=1)
```

As far as I can see the format is correct, and the code runs fine on other machines.

It works when I remove the %z from the format and just take a slice of the data to be formatted, for example as below:

```
df['yearmonth'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.strptime(row['createdAt'][:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').strftime("%Y%m"), axis=1)
```

So I'm guessing that %z is causing issues. I'm figuring that the issue is to do with locales but I've tried setting locale in all different sorts of ways without success.

Would really appreciate some insight on how to fix this without using the slice!

Comment: Strange, the data _looks_ like it should parse... Maybe it contains some unprintable characters? Please provide a [mcve] that constructs your dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While parsing of '%z' is supported by Python 3.6, when in this format:

`+HHMM or -HHMM`

it does not support parsing of the '%z' if this section of the date includes a colon:

`+HH:MM or -HH:MM`

However, Python 3.7 does support parsing of the '%z' section when there is a colon in this section.

Therefore, using Python 3.7 instead of Python 3.6 will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The **Python 2** `strptime()` function indeed does **not support the %z** format for timezones (because the underlying time.strptime() function doesn't support it). You have two options:

Ignore the timezone when parsing with strptime:

```
time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str[:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

use the dateutil module, it's parse function does deal with timezones:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
time_obj = parse(time_str)
```

You could also upgrade to **Python 3.2** or newer, where timezone support has been improved to the point that `%z` would work, provided you remove the last : from the input, and the - from before the %z

Comment: Ah sorry didn't see your answer before I posted mine. You just earned a +1 :p

Comment: It doesn't work also for me with python 3.6.5. Shouldn't timezone be in the format "+HHMM or -HHMM" without colon to be read with %z?

Comment: We're already using Python 3.6 so really it should be working, and works in other places where we're using it in a similar way, that's why I'm a bit confused and leads me towards thinking it is a locale issue - I will look into dateutil though.

Edit - looking closer at the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) it looks like @FedOpp could be right and it's due to a colon being in the %z part - strangely though, we have this exact setup working on another server.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, consider using `dateutil` :

```py
import datetime
import dateutil.parser

my_date_str = '2019-07-05T10:19:42+00:00'
my_date = dateutil.parser.parse(my_date_str)
print(type(my_date)) # <class 'datetime.datetime'>  
print(my_date.strftime('%Y%m')) # 201907
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at dateutil and see if that will work for us.